# Getting started with augmented reality using Processing/Processing.js

Tags: processing, augmented-reality, processing.js

Are there any good resources to begin with? Are there any interesting applications of the same?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a great one.  Check out what this guy is doing with his web cam to control music and graphics based on the positioning of his hands.  Skip ahead to about 2:40 if you are impatient.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DW3AR9PFY84

Here is the code information for it.
https://github.com/ACassells/processing.js.SimpleWebCamInteraction

In this picture the guy moves his hands around to control where the graphics are located.

[image]